# How to properly Retrieve last quarter sales values from a fact table

Tags: sql, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I was working on two aproach one, using lag functions and the other is the next:

my dataframe looks like this

```
+----------+-----------+-----+------+----+-------+------------+---------+
|product_id|customer_id|sales|period|year|quarter|prev_quarter|prev_year|
+----------+-----------+-----+------+----+-------+------------+---------+
|        24|          2|  288|     8|2022|      3|           2|     2022|
|        14|          5|  527|     1|2022|      1|           4|     2021|
|        32|          3|  763|     6|2022|      2|           1|     2022|
|        25|          5|  175|     4|2022|      2|           1|     2022|
|        36|          5|  840|     1|2023|      1|           4|     2022|
|        37|          3|  471|    11|2021|      4|           3|     2021|
|         4|          1|  990|     7|2023|      3|           2|     2023|
|        42|          1|  225|    10|2023|      4|           3|     2023|
|        24|          5|  951|     4|2020|      2|           1|     2020|
|        25|          1|  531|    10|2023|      4|           3|     2023|
|         2|          4|  802|     7|2021|      3|           2|     2021|
|        34|          2|  950|    12|2023|      4|           3|     2023|
|        13|          5|  916|     3|2020|      1|           4|     2019|
|        28|          3|  432|     2|2020|      1|           4|     2019|
```

And i did the same to bring previous quarter values
I created a auxiliar dataframe and I add the sum agregation I need. then I joined to the original dataframe

```
df_kpi = df
df_kpi = df_kpi.groupBy("year", "quarter", "product_id").agg(sum(col("sales")).alias('sales_total'))


df_joined = df.alias('df').join(
    df_kpi.alias('kpi'),
    (col("df.product_id") == col('kpi.product_id')) &
    (col('df.prev_quarter') == col('kpi.quarter')) &
    (col('df.prev_year') == col("kpi.year")),
    "left"
).select("df.year", "df.prev_year","df.quarter", "df.sales", "df.period","df.prev_quarter", "df.product_id", "df.customer_id", "kpi.sales_total")
```

it looks that it works individually by product id in some cases:
for example doing this display

```
df_joined.filter(col('product_id')==36).groupBy('quarter', "period","year","product_id").agg(sum(col('sales_total'))).orderBy('quarter', "year").show()
```

prints:

```
+------+-------+----+------------+----------------+
|period|quarter|year|prev_quarter|sum(sales_total)|
+------+-------+----+------------+----------------+
|     5|      2|2020|           1|             981|
|     4|      2|2020|           1|             981|
|     6|      2|2020|           1|             981|
|     5|      2|2022|           1|            NULL|
|     6|      2|2023|           1|            1386|
|     4|      2|2023|           1|            1386|
|     9|      3|2021|           2|            NULL|
|     9|      3|2022|           2|             580|
|     8|      3|2023|           2|            1581|
|    10|      4|2021|           3|             383|
|    11|      4|2021|           3|             766|
|    10|      4|2022|           3|             467|
|    12|      4|2023|           3|             255|
|    10|      4|2023|           3|             255|
|     1|      1|2020|           4|            NULL|
|     3|      1|2021|           4|            NULL|
|     2|      1|2021|           4|            NULL|
|     1|      1|2021|           4|            NULL|
|     1|      1|2023|           4|             244|
|     3|      1|2023|           4|             244|
+------+-------+----+------------+----------------+
```

when I do a sum calculation for every product by year and quarter, it is supossed to show the same value for the quarter and the year, but its not happening, how would you suggest to solve it?
Actual result:

```
+----+------+-------+----------+
|year|period|quarter|sum(sales)|
+----+------+-------+----------+
|2020|     2|      1|      NULL|
|2020|     3|      1|      NULL|
|2020|     1|      1|      NULL|
|2020|     6|      2|      4550|
|2020|     5|      2|      6675|
|2020|     4|      2|      2555|
|2020|     8|      3|     10354|
|2020|     7|      3|      4059|
|2020|     9|      3|      3255|
|2020|    10|      4|      5445|
|2020|    11|      4|      2684|
|2020|    12|      4|      1480|
|2021|     1|      1|      1385|
|2021|     3|      1|      2421|
```

Desired Output:

```
+----+------+-------+----------+
|year|period|quarter|sum(sales)|
+----+------+-------+----------+
|2020|     2|      1|      NULL|
|2020|     3|      1|      NULL|
|2020|     1|      1|      NULL|
|2020|     6|      2|      4550|
|2020|     5|      2|      4550|
|2020|     4|      2|      4550 
|2020|     8|      3|     10354|
|2020|     7|      3|     10354|
|2020|     9|      3|     10354|
|2020|    10|      4|      5445|
|2020|    11|      4|     5445|
|2020|    12|      4|      5445|
```

Basically, I need to add a sum agregation by product, year and quarter of the column sales. Then after I get all the previous quarter values for sales, grouping them by quarter and year and apply it a sum
thank you in advance

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. If your sample data showed more information about product 36 then perhaps the second table might make sense. Perhaps if you also provided the **expected result** then we might understand what needs to be fixed.

Comment: @PaulMaxwell sorry if i didnt explain myself better, I need to retrieve the sum agregation for sales column by quarter, year and product id but for the previous quarters, for example if the current quarter is 4 then the data displayed must be the sales from the previous quarter. then calculate all the sales by periods and quarters. Like is shown in the second table, but only works testing independently by one product ID like is shown in the table, but when I apply a total sum for every product by quarters and years, it doesnt shown correctly. I will add a third table to show how it looks

Comment: You might need a dataframe for all years and quarters (df_calendar) then "left join" the existing df and the df_kpi to that df_calendar. The problem you may have is gaps in the source data.

Comment: Sorry maybe I don't understand, but the fact dataframe has all the periods , years, and quarters needed. Or what do you exactly mean?

Answer (score 0):

The aggregation in df_kpi gives you "current quarter" values, to get the "sales_total" of the previous quarter shift that column by using the lag function. e.g:

```
df_joined = df.alias('df').join(
    df_kpi.alias('kpi'),
    (col("df.product_id") == col('kpi.product_id')) &
    (col('df.quarter') == col('kpi.quarter')) &
    (col('df.year') == col("kpi.year")),
    "left"
).select("df.year", "df.prev_year","df.quarter", "df.sales", "df.period","df.prev_quarter", "df.product_id", "df.customer_id", "kpi.sales_total")

window = Window.partitionBy('product_id').orderBy('year', 'quarter')
df_joined = df_joined.withColumn('sales_total_prev_quarter', F.lag('sales_total').over(window))
```

Comment: It works individually if I check for a product ID specifically, but after apply the sum for sales by product id, and try to do a sum for each period and year after, it doesnt work, I dont know why, but im still trying to figure it out.

Comment: I will try to explain myself better, I need to add a sum agregation by product, year and quarter. Then after that get all the previous quarter values, and after that grouping them by quarter and year.

Comment: if I can be so bold. You need to use sample data that directly relates to the desired final outcome. i.e. it should be possible to produce the final outcome from only the sample data you provide. At the moment the numbers in the final outcome seem arbitrary and the sample data has too many products and not enough month/quarters. Also be specific in column headings is "sum(sales)" the "current_qtr" or "previous_qtr".